# I need to create a 2D array from JSON data for a 'Datatables plugin for jQuery' table

Tags: jquery, arrays, datatables

My 2D `testtable` array works as expected filling the rows in the table.
My `tabledata` array created from JSON data creates an array but will not fill the rows in the table. For some reason it seems Datatables won't recognize the array as an array. There are no errors in the console. Just a message in the table stating "No data available in table". I'm a confused because the `tabledata` array should work. Any ideas why it does not. I tried creating the `tabledata` array a few other ways with no luck.

```
var tableData = [];
var testTable = [['1','2','3','4','5','6'], ['7','8','9','10','11','12']]

$(function() {
    populateTableDataArray('data/test.json');
    $('#example').DataTable({
        data: tableData
    });
    console.log(tableData);
});

function populateTableDataArray(file) {
    $.getJSON(file, function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
            tableData.push([value[0], value[1], value[2], value[6], value[7], value[8]]);
        });
    });
};
```

Test JSON data

```
{"1": ["4999", "HARVEST MARKET", "2285 MARKET St", "San Francisco", "37.764607", "-122.432452", "2016-10-03T00:00:00", "77", "High risk food holding temperature", "High Risk"], "2": ["2134", "CHIEFTAIN IRISH PUB, THE", "198 05th St", "San Francisco", "37.781567", "-122.405059", "2016-11-09T00:00:00", "87", "High risk food holding temperature", "High Risk"]}
```

Output from Datatables using tabledata array
[image: Output from Datatables using tabledata array]

Output from Datatables using testtable array

[image: op from db using testtable]

Comment: ajax is **asynchronous**.  You need to initialize the plugin after the `getJSON` completes. Right now you are passing empty array to the plugin

Comment: @davidkonrad the `$.each` iterates the object. Agree that the structure of endpoint response is strange but `tabledata` should be 2d array based on code shown

Comment: @charlietfl, You are right. I misread the test JSON as the output, must be tired :( Have posted an example how to do it from within dataTables itself.

Comment: @davidkonrad That is the main problem. I'm able to convert the object literal to an array using `Object.values(data)` however the docs say it's supported only in Chrome & FireFox.

Comment: @y2knoproblem, ? `$.each(data, function(key, value) {` works in any (modern) browser.  Does the below answer not work in Edge, Safari or Opera? Your problem was asynchronicity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As *charlietf* mentions, the problem is asynchronicity. A quick workaround could be to load the JSON from within dataTables itself, and then reuse your code from `populateTableDataArray()` in the `dataSrc` callback :

```js
$('#example').DataTable({
   ajax: {
     url: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/1dtiov',
     dataSrc: function(data) {
       var tableData = [];
       $.each(data, function(key, value) {
         tableData.push([value[0], value[1], value[2], value[6], value[7], value[8]]);
       });
       return tableData
     }
   },
   columns: [
     { data: 0, title: '1'}, //TODO, add some meaningful titles
     { data: 1, title: '2'},
     { data: 2, title: '3'},
     { data: 3, title: '4'},
     { data: 4, title: '5'}    
   ]
})
```

markup

```html
<table id="example"></table>
```

see it in action -> **http://jsfiddle.net/yzrshckf/**

Replace the myjson.com reference with the path to your JSON, i.e `data/test.json`.

Comment: I was able to work it converting `data` to an array using `Object.values(data)`. However, that fix will only work in Chrome, Firefox. Your solution should work across all platforms so I will go with that. Thanks.